# Intel XDK uploadToServer callback not being called

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk

I am uploading an image to my server the following way:

```
function onImageSuccess(event) {
        if (event.success === true) {
            var serviceUrl = <my api url>;
            var url = intel.xdk.camera.getPictureURL(event.filename);
            intel.xdk.file.uploadToServer(url, serviceUrl + 'image/upload', '', 'image/png', "updateUploadProgress");
}
```

I then have the callback defined as such:

```
    function updateUploadProgress(bytesSent,totalBytes) {alert('test');
        if(totalBytes>0) {
            currentProgress=(bytesSent/totalBytes)*100;
            alert(currentProgress);
            console.log(currentProgress);
        }
    }
```

However, none of my alerts in my callback get called. No errors pop up. My upload complete listener fires off successfully. I cannot figure out why my callback isn't being reached.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. As a note, it seems this API call is only for iOS or Android, no WP support. I notice running on WP causes a silent failure rather than some type of "not implemented" error. However, when I do this on iOS it says it can't find the file to upload, which is odd as it is coming from the src attribute of an image that I can plainly see is fine.